# Different notation for cipher suites between Scala and Python

Tags: python, scala, ssl, encryption, tls1.2

I'm having an issue using cipher suites for my client written in Scala and my server written in Python.
The client uses the following SSLEngine with some enabled cipher suites:

```
val engine = sslContext.createSSLEngine()
engine.setEnabledProtocols(Array[String]("TLSv1.2"))
engine.setEnabledCipherSuites(Array[String]("TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384", "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256", "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384"))
```

The server Python is configured as follows:

```
context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
context.set_ciphers('ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384')
```

As you can see, the 3 cipher suites defined for both client and server are the same, only the notation changes. But in this way, when client send a request to the server, the server logs the error `[SSL: NO_SHARED_CIPHER] no shared cipher (_ssl.c:2309)`.

I tried to set in Python the same strings used in Scala but the server logs the error `ssl.SSLError: ('No cipher can be selected.',)`

How can I fix this discrepancy? Is it normal?

Comment: Has the server configured an RSA or ECC certificate? In the first case only the RSA cipher is relevant, in the second case only the ECDSA ciphers. And do both client and server really support these ciphers in the first place, which depends on the version of the TLS stack used and maybe some configuration. As for debugging I would recommend to not limit the ciphers at all on both sides (i.e. use defaults) and then gradually exclude more and more ciphers on the server side  (i.e. every cipher which was used but which you don't want to have included).